Problem about libifcoremd.dll when using VS2022 compiler
Working environment:

Windows 11 Professional  23H2
VS 2022 community 17.9.6
OneAPI 2024.1

I was running a fortran program release on the VS and the terminal unexpectedly freezed. I had to terminate it manually using the task manager. Then I found out that I can not compile any fortran code correctly. The error message says No symbol file loaded for libifcoremd.dll.
I`ve searched it online and Im pretty sure that my code is totally fine.
I used the dependency inspector BinInspector, and found out that there is something wrong with my dlls.
BinInspector Result
But these dlls are just right there.dlls
And the path of environment varibles is correct, too.path
I dont know how to deal with this situation, please help me with it.
Thanks.

"No symbol file loaded for " is not an error, it's just informational, It's telling you that DEBUG symbols have not been loaded. Which is what I would expect as the dll you are referencing is the RELEASE dll.

@user20716902 Availability of debug symbols is somewhat orthogonal to being a debug or release build.  Probably more to the point, it's the Fortran runtime from Intel.  You probably don't need symbols.  If you really do, then you should check on Intel's docs and/or follow up with Intel support.

When it says "no symbol file loaded" it means that there wasn't a .pdb file (or it wasn't able to find it), it doesn't mean that the library itself failed to load.  If you want to know if a library loaded, you can set a breakpoint in your code and look at the loaded modules list (ctl-alt-u) which will show you everything that is loaded and where it loaded from.

Intel do not distribute the .pdb's with OneAPI, so the message is to be expected.

The warning message (not error!) is a red herring. If you really cannot compile any Fortran code, show us what exactly you are doing and what exactly happens. Step by steps with all commands and messages that appear.

The missing pdb file indicates that your debugger does not have necessary information to dig into this assembly but this will not cause your application to crash. To figure out what happened to your code compilation, you need to provide more detail about what you are trying to do and check if there is any output from compiler log. If this issue happened on runtime, then you may try collecting dumps of your program or try time-travel-debugging.
